# How should I adjust warped balcony door frame?

Tags: doors

I'm living in an older apartment building, and I've noticed that I'm losing a fair amount of heat due to a gap in my balcony doors. Specifically, the sliding glass door fails to form a seal with the frame at the top.

What's the best way to solve this? The sliding door itself doesn't appear to have any aligning mechanism that I can use. The only thing I can think of is filling the slot for the most part, and then adding some weather seal that it can push against.

[image: Crack between Sliding Door and Frame]
[image: Balcony Doors]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to see from the photos, but sliding doors are typically leveled (or fit to their stationary counterparts) by turning screw or cam adjusters controlling the height of the two wheels on which they roll.

Look for plastic plugs covering screw access holes near the bottom of the door, and use an appropriately-sized screwdriver to adjust them. It may be helpful to have someone lift pressure off the door while you do so.

Comment: That was the solution, I looked closer and found a screw unlocking an adjusting dial of sorts. Thanks!